# Need help resolving error CS1701 in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am working in a script that is generating an error that I have not been able to find a solution.  I am using PowerShell version 7.4.1 and 5.1.  Both versions produce the same error.

```
Import-Module SqlServer

# Succeeds with no error.
$Test = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database]::New()

$TypeDefinition = @'
using System.Runtime;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyDatabase
    {
        public Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database Database;

        public MyDatabase(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database SmoDatabase)
        {
            this.Database = SmoDatabase;
        }
    }
}
'@

$ReferencedAssemblies = @(
    [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().where({$_.ManifestModule.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'}).Location
)

$TypeParameters = @{
    TypeDefinition = $TypeDefinition
    ReferencedAssemblies = $ReferencedAssemblies
}

# Generates Error
Add-Type @TypeParameters
```

This code results in error:

> error CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' used by 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' matches identity 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of 'System.Runtime', you may need to supply runtime policy

How do I correct this error?

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` are you using?

Comment: It is the version that is packages with Microsoft's SqlServer module version 22.2.0.  The dll version is 17.100.13.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently C# compilation warnings result in an error with the Add-Type cmdlet.  The reference from [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11112) offers the solution.  Changing the $TypeParameters as below resolves the problem.

```
$TypeParameters = @{
    TypeDefinition = $TypeDefinition
    ReferencedAssemblies = $ReferencedAssemblies
    WarningAction = 'Ignore'
    IgnoreWarnings = $true
}
```